# Datatable one ajax result to multiple tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

What I'm trying to do is after initially datatables with ajax to get results for 3 different stores (this part work fine) and separate data into 3 different tables I dont like to send 3 ajax to fill up the tables so is there anyway to do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('table').DataTable( {
   "ajax": "data/getData.php"
    });

if(data.store_id == 1){
  $(data).append('#table1')
 }elseif(data.store_id == 2){
  $(data).append('#table2')
 }
});
```

Comment: One possible approach is shown in this question: [How to use one ajax datasource with multiple JQuery Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495442/how-to-use-one-ajax-datasource-with-multiple-jquery-datatables/65497149#65497149). That example has 2 target tables, but can be extended to cover 3 tables. You may need to provide more details (for example, by showing some sample JSON data), if this does not meet your needs.

Comment: @andrewjames I think this will do the job, your star